# How can I get data after post request and set it to state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
            "script": "string",
            "name": "string",
            "type": "string"
        }
    )
})
    .then(function (data) {
        return data.resolve()
    }).then(()=>{
        //set data to state
})
```

How can I handle data after post request and set to state or I ned get it in get request after post?

Comment: change
`.then(function (data) { return data.resolve()}).then(()=>{ //set data to state}) `

to

    `.then(function (data) { return data.json(); }).then(result=>{ //set data (result) to state})`

Answer (score 0):

First of all , I recommend you to use axios library to make data fetchinng easier and do that:

```
const response = await axios.post(url)
setState(response.data)
```

You make a request to get the response from the api. And you add the data of the response to your state